# Gulp error downloading files

Tags: angularjs, gulp, gulp-connect

I'm creating an Angular application using gulp and gulp connect to deploy the web app. If I use gulp 3.8.11 and gulp-connect 2.0.6 I can download file using the following way:

```
<a href="../files/formato.xls">
```

The problem is when I upgrade the gulp and gulp-connect to the last versions, when I download a file the file is corrupted with a bad format.

How can I download files with the last versions of gulp and gulp-connect?